# How to run Cypress on browser in Raspberry Pi

Tags: cypress

In general Cypress can be run on a web browser.
I have a custom OS in RbPi which has inbuilt browser in it.

Is there any possibility of running Cypress in RbPi.?

Answer (score -3):

The Cypress [Continuous Integration documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html) contains information regarding running the test runner on various build agents and platforms.

**Running Cypress in Docker:**

Your easiest route is to run Cypress within their supported Docker image, which will ensure that the runtime environment has all of the necessary dependencies installed.

See their documentation on running within Docker: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Docker

This approach has some limitations; namely that the test runner will run headless (without a browser window visible) unless viewing it using a somewhat-complicated X11 setup.

---

**Running Cypress natively:**

When running on low-powered device like the RaspberryPi, you may wish to avoid the unnecessary system performance impact caused by Docker.

See the Cypress Advanced Setup documentation, which includes a section which lists the required System Dependencies: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Dependencies